# Do end of year statements take longer to generate than mid-year statements?

Tags: financial-statements

I logged into several of my retirement accounts to download all of their most recent quarterly statements and found a few did not have their statements rendered yet for download.

Is there some seasonal thing to this, where end of year has this larger than normal demand for statement computations that have to go through review or something more involved to verify all the rolled up numbers are correct before they go into the corresponding tax forms and all that? Does the generation of those tax forms back things up possibly?

Comment: An end of year statement is merely a recap of all transactions for the year (trades, dividends, interest, margin costs, etc.).  Tax forms are far more complicated since they require much more detailed info, for example, the pairing of trades and determination of wash sale violations.  So yes, tax numbers are far more detailed and have to be reviewed before submitting to the IRS (U.S.) but that shouldn't impede receiving an EOY statement since tax info usually isn't completed and submitted until February.

Comment: How late is the statement compared with previous quarters? The first business day was the 4th due to holiday and the weekend.  I have one bill that always takes 5 days after the close of the cycle to be able to download the pdf, others take less than a day.